# CKEditor 5 - VueJS - Toolbar not wrapped when text field is smaller than width of all items combined

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

When the width of all the toolbar items exceeds the toolbar width it moves all the items into a submenu (3 dots on the right) instead on other versions I've seend it either wrap them to a new line (prefered) or just move a few items into the submenu.

[image: all gone]

As you see they are all gone if I press that ... menu it shows up as a big line.

[image: wrapped in the... menu]

I'm using the ckeditor5-vue library following the vue integration guide from the website for ckeditor + added a few additional items to the menu.

There is no documentation on how to manually warp or anything on the toolbar. All help appreciated.

Comment: Hi! It looks like a bug in CKE5 or some very weird styles that you used. I think that the right place to discuss this would be via https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the option `shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true` for toolbar config to solve that problem:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have set `shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true` and the three dots are still appearing even though the list of items is smaller than width of the editor size:

[image]

I am using CK editor 5 with Vue:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^34.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the config option to the CK editor,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G5BZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5eJ4.png)

Above are my code and it works for me!